# Offset Timeline for Multiple Linked Objects

Tags: python, animation, linked-data, nla-editor, timeline

I'd like to be able to link to groups from a series of .blend files so that the models appear in a single .blend file so I can animate a camera between them, but make updates to the individual .blend files dynamically.

Is there a way to offset the animation timelines for each linked instance of the groups in the main .blend file so they play their internal animations at different, specified points in the main timeline?

Each .blend file has an internal animation that starts at frame 0.

In my main .blend file, I'd like to specify something like this:

group from scene1.blend - start your animation at frame 10

group from scene2.blend - start your animation at frame 100

group from scene3.blend - start your animation at frame 150

I've seen a few past answers to this question but they involved using NLA tracks and python - this seems like a simple enough scenario so as not to require much complexity.